# how can i change string into vector in python

Tags: python, word2vec

i have one data-frame ,here it is

```
     name
  1  mike
  2 jemmie
  3  lusi
```

now i want to convert those name using `word2vec`

```
     name      vec1
  1  mike      vecValue of mike
  2 jemmie     vecValue of jemmie 
  3  lusi      vecValue of lusi
```

i did simple code but it gives me `<gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab at 0x7f5f0c020d68>` this value

but i need a `array of arrays`  or any `int` or `float` value

how can i do that?

help will be appreciated

Thanks